# Grammatical purpose of changing 〜る to 〜な, and expressing "even"

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-でも

I have to translate the following for my intro Japanese class.

> 父は、少し、働き**すぎな**ので、庭の花や木に水**でも**やって、リラックスした方がいいとおもいます。

I understand parts of the sentence, but not the sentence as a whole.

I think `父は、少し、働きすぎなので` is `My father works a little too much so`. But, I don't understand why it's `すぎな` and not `すぎる`.

I think `庭の花や木に水でもやって` is `Someone gives water even to the garden flower and the tree (etc)`. I am not sure how the "even" should be though.

Finally, I think `リラックスした方がいいとおもいます` is `I think it is better if he relaxes`.

So my questions are

1. Why the `な` instead of a `る` on the first part?
2. How is the `even` placed in the second part?
3. How do all three parts form a logical sentence?

My best guess is `My father works a little too hard so, since someone even gives water to the garden flower and the tree (etc), I think it is better if he relaxes.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [働きすぎ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E) is a 名詞 which comes from verb 働き過ぎる(働く+過ぎる). 
   eg 食べすぎ / 飲みすぎ / 太りすぎ (+ だ/です)
   [デジタル大辞泉 verb+過ぎ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/117536/m0u/%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E/)
2. The でも is used to give examples. [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/152508/m0u/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82/)(See meaning #2-3)
3. The subject for 庭の花や木に水でもやって is 父.

父は、少し、働きすぎなので、My father is a little overworked, so
庭の花や木に水でもやって　(I think he should spend time doing things like) watering trees or flowers in his garden 
 
リラックスした方がいいとおもいます。I think he should relax

Comment: Are you sure ○○すぎ is a 形容動詞? I've never seen them used with 〜な before, except where 名詞 can normally be used with 〜な (「父は、医者なの（で・だ・です）」, etc.)

Comment: No, I am not sure...

Comment: I just found it's a 名詞. [This page](http://nihongo.do-bunkyodai.ac.jp/qandaDisp.php?id=285) says...「食べすぎです」はその複合動詞「食べすぎる」を名詞化してできた派生名詞「食べすぎ」に断定の助動詞「です」を付加した述語です。

Comment: http://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E2%80%9D%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AA%E4%BA%BA%E2%80%9D&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8&fr=top_ga1_sa&x=wrt

Comment: @TokyoNagoya どっちやねん！

Comment: どっちもどっちやろな。ええ勝負や。その人なりの見解でええんちゃう？

Comment: @TokyoNagoya えええそんなんでいいのおおお

Comment: @ちょこれーと　ええねん。国語学者の間でも意見が分かれてるみたいや。TNちゃんも迷っちゃう、ウフっ。